# scaling a image to 1/4 of size (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimageview, scale, uibezierpath

I am trying to scale myPicture to a lower size. I am trying to make it 1/4th of its current size. To test the effect of scaling the image with bezierPath. Ideally I would like my picture to be display in the bottom left in a 1/4 of the procure current size.

```
import UIKit



   extension UIImageView {
func addMask(_ bezierPath: UIBezierPath) {
    let pathMask = CAShapeLayer()
    pathMask.path = bezierPath.cgPath
    layer.mask = pathMask
}
 }

  let myPicture = UIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string:"https://a248.e.akamai.net/secure.meetupstatic.com/photos/member/5/3/5/e/highres_260901342.jpeg")!))!

  let iv = UIImageView(image: myPicture)

   let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
 bezierPath.move(to: iv.center)
 bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: iv.frame.maxY, y: 0))
bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: iv.frame.maxX, y: iv.frame.maxY))
 bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: iv.frame.maxY))
  bezierPath.addLine(to: .zero)



 bezierPath.close()

  iv.addMask(bezierPath)
```

The code is outputs this image. 
[image]

Comment: What is your desired result here? The black triangle is there only because you are missing an extra point bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: iv.frame.maxY, y: 0)) before the zero.

Comment: I just want to shrink the image to the bottom left of the image in a 1/4 of the size. The bezier path would still apply however it should not be seen because the path does not overlap with the pitcure. I just want to see if that works. All I want to do is shrink the image of the guy wearing the blue polo shirt.